# Setting automatic colour in selected cell

Tags: excel, vba, colors

I have developed a worksheet in which when I open it, select the cell with today's date.

What I want to do is to colour the whole column in which the cell with date is placed. Here is the script I am using for now. What I have done so far, is to colour the selected cell with the date. But for some unknown to me reason, prior colouring the cell I want, it selects and colours one random cell.

This is the code I have used:
Code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim CellToShow As Range
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Select
    x = Day(Date)
    Set CellToShow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows(2).Find(What:=x, LookIn:=xlValues)
    Selection.Interior.Color = RGB(151, 228, 255) 'background colour in the selected cell
    If CellToShow Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No Cell for day " & x & " found.", vbCritical
    Else
        With CellToShow
            .Select
            .Show 'Scroll the window to show the cell
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `CellToShow.Interior.Color = RGB(151, 228, 255)` or change to entire column if that is what you are trying to do.

Comment: Your suggestion resolves the problem that I have with selecting only the selected cell (without prior selecting any other cell).  But I want to colour the whole column in which the selected cell is located.

Comment: The line `Selection.Interior.Color = RGB(151, 228, 255) 'background colour in the selected cell` is not doing what you think it does. It assigns the colour to the cell you have currently selected in your sheet. It's not doing anything with `CellToShow`. If you want to colour the whole column where `CellToShow` is located, then you want to use: `CellToShow.EntireColumn.Interior.Color = RGB(151, 228, 255)`